# Codeigniter and mod_rewrite, rewrite not working and 404 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've an issue with CodeIgniter and the mod_rewrite module.
In Apache i followed all the instruction i found in the ellislab's blog. So removing index.php worked as well. Now i have this file .htaccess:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteBase /
    #RewriteRule ^box/$    create/$1   # Handle requests for "pet-care"
    RewriteRule ^about/$ aboutus
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]


</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # In caso di mancanza di installazione del modulo mod_rewrite,
    # tutte le pagine 404 possono essere inviate ad index.php
    # e tutto funzionera' normalmente

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

The thing i can't get to work is the line

```
#RewriteRule ^about/$ aboutus
```

I want to rewrite my localhost/aboutus in localhost/about . I've a controller called aboutus, which refer to a view aboutus. 
Another issue is when i've a url structure like this:

```
localhost/controller/function/param1/param2
```

and i want to convert in:

```
localhost/myname/param1
```

Can't figure it out :(

Comment: you should user `config/route.php` to route such type `uri` for more info https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you would just configure:

```
$route['product/(:num)'] = "catalog/product_lookup_by_id/$1";
```

in this url:

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

you can find some exapmles I think will be help